# Datafactory No Activities in this pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have the simple pipeline to copy from on prem SQL Server to Azure SQL Database.

However, no data is moved over and simply notes: `No Activities in this pipeline`

What are the issues with this pipeline?

```
{
    "name": "OnPrem-to-Cloud",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Copy data from on prem to Azure SQL",
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "SqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "select * from table"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlSink",
                        "writeBatchSize": 0,
                        "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "source-table"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "destination-table"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "01:00:00",
                    "concurrency": 1
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "name": "CopyFromSQlServerToAzureSQL",
                "description": "copy activity"
            }
        ],
        "start": "2017-08-29T21:55:29.438863Z",
        "end": "2017-08-29T21:55:29.438863Z",
        "isPaused": false,
        "hubName": "data-factory-prod_hub",
        "pipelineMode": "OneTime",
        "expirationTime": "3.00:00:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: please update your end date to one day further. there should be some gap between start date and end date and in your case, it should be 1 day or something.

Comment: Also you can try Copy Wizard to create proper ADF which is very easy and quick for any number of tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is misleading. Its not that there's no activity in the pipeline. Its that there is nothing for ADF to provision when you deploy it because your start and end date times are the same.

This means that ADF can't create any times slices and time slices are the things that actually do the execution.

As already suggested in the comments above you need to extend your end date, but also changed the pipelineMode to scheduled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thank you

Comment: Great. Happy to help.

Comment: To elaborate on this, this issue occurs whenever a reference is made to `{Window, Slice}{Start, End}` but the job is a onetimer. Usually such references are found in the referenced datasets, e.g. a `yyyy/mm/dd` output path.